# SVN should I ask to have a new branch created or a new repository altogether?

Tags: svn

we have a SVN-repo with a bunch of projects [they are related to each other.. loosely coupled with each other .. i.e. dojo-javascript in project calls some csharp objects in another]. I am in the process of making sort of a disruptive code changes to one of these projects for an interim-release which has limited scope. This means, some of the features that used to work won't work any more in this release, but that's acceptable for the product/customers etc.

So, I wonder, if I should make these code changes in a branch and make a release out of this branch? (OR) create a new repository altogether. Eventually, we would fix-up all the issues and would bring it back to Trunk.

Also, one more minor detail, currently I am the only person modifying stuff in these group of projects.

Please advise. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch. That's exactly what they're for. I don't see any advantage to a new repository in this case, unless the changes you intend to make are going to have irreversible effects on the repository, like adding very large binary files, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed asked the admin for a Branch.. he suggested that he can create a repository instead.. thus got confused and started asking around for opinions.

Comment: After further discussions and such.. we have created a branch and life is all back to normal. Thanks for the quick reply.